# 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'member'

Tags: discord, discord.py

Im having this issue and i still cant find a solution this is the code

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == commands.reaction_message.id and commands.reaction_role != None:
        await payload.member.add_roles(commands.reaction_role)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == commands.reaction_message.id and commands.reaction_role != None:
        guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        await member.remove_roles(commands.reaction_role)
@commands.command()
async def set_reaction_message(self, ctx, message_id=None, role_id=None):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        try:
            commands.reaction_message = await channel.fetch_message(int(message_id))
            break

        except:
            pass
```

problem:   File "c:\Users\MY-NAME\Desktop\Overige en school\Discord Bot\cogs\reaction.py", line 17, in on_raw_reaction_add
await payload.member.add_roles(commands.reaction_role)
AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'member'

can someone please help me this is been bothering me now for 2days and i can't even find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I know according to the documentation [discord.RawReactionActionEvent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) payload has the object member. But why don't you make it easier for yourself and get the member in the same way as in your on_raw_reaction_remove event? The following should work.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == commands.reaction_message.id and commands.reaction_role != None:
        guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        await member.add_roles(commands.reaction_role)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == commands.reaction_message.id and commands.reaction_role != None:
        guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        await member.remove_roles(commands.reaction_role)

@commands.command()
async def set_reaction_message(self, ctx, message_id=None, role_id=None):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        try:
            commands.reaction_message = await channel.fetch_message(int(message_id))
            break

        except:
            pass
```